# How to find the sum of all numbers between 1 and N using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the sum of all numbers between 1 to N using JavaScript. The following is the code I have tried so far but it doesn't seem to work.

```
function numberSum(N) {
  var total = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= N; i++){
      total += i;
    }
    return total;
}
```

I have tried using jslint and other validators online to check if I might have missed something but that doesn't seem to help me find the reason for the code not working either. Is there something that I'm missing above that's preventing the script from executing the addition??

Comment: Your code is fine. How do you call it?

Comment: Why do you say this "doesn't seem to work"? How are you getting the result out of your function? Are you getting an unexpected result, or no result at all?

Comment: What is the input, what is the output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: why is it not working? are you getting some error?

Comment: @Saagar No result and no errors in the console either :(

Comment: You may get an error somewhere else in your js and the function may not get called because of that. Or maybe you call the function before it is defined. Anyway... there is no problem in the code you posted. Or... after reading your comment... do you call the function at all?

Comment: see the answer below. it might be the way you are displaying your result... paste the code where you are accessing or displaying your result...

Comment: @AndrewLyndem check my answer below, it is because you are not calling the function, or not telling it to print the result anywhere.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your code is fine.

Keep it simple:

```
var res = (n * (n+1)) / 2;
```

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Comment: Maybe not exactly related with current question but the tip is ok... doesn't deserve a -2.

Comment: @zozo - I'll quote the question: "How to find the sum of all numbers between 1 and N using JavaScript" and the first line of his message: 
"I'm trying to find a way to calculate the sum of all numbers between 1 to N using JavaScript." Now I've added that his code is ok and I don't really see a reason for the downvotes.

Comment: This works beautifully!! And it's way more cleaner than the one I wrote too. But I don't understand why my version is not working though.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem - your code is ok. It's weird that it doesn't work. Did you copy-paste it from somewhere? try to re-type it and it will run.

Comment: @Max `window.numberSum(N);` bro.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem - Are you sure the method is on the global "window" scope? try to replace your code with console.log((function numberSum(N) {
  var total = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= N; i++){
      total += i;
    }
    return total;
})(5))

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you might want to answer the actual problem the OP is facing.

Comment: @A.J. - What problem? His code is ok and has no problem. I'm trying to help him through the comments though.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem - Can you show your complete code? It looks like the function isn't on the window for some reason.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem - Maybe your function is wrapped by another function or something. Anyway read about javascript scopes.

Comment: @AmirPopovich, his problem was *it doesn't seem to work*, not *can you give me a better formula?* But nice code anyways

Comment: @A.J. - We fixed both problems :)

Comment: @AmirPopovich +1 for showing the OP a better approach. Can't we omit the wrapping `()` though? `=>  n * (n + 1) / 2`

Comment: I absolutely love it when programmers use their math skills to cut out a for loop. +1 from me!

Answer (score 7):

Your code runs fine. How did you run it?

Demo:

```js
function numberSum(N) {
  var total = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i <= N; i++){
      total += i;
    }
    return total;
}

function run(){
  val = document.getElementById("val").value;
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=val+": "+numberSum(val)
  }
```

```html
<input id="val">
<input type="Submit" onclick="run();">
<p id="results"></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is already solved but I wanted to post a quick ES6 oneliner I wrote after reading this thread and explain it more thoroughly for others who like me don't have a solid math background.

```
const numSum = (n) => n * (n+1) / 2;
```

It works because it uses a [mathematic formula that Carl Friedrich Gauss came up with](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-sum-of-1-to-100). (this has a great image).

Basically, whenever you are adding the sum of n numbers, you will have pairs in the sequence. So Gauss figured out that you didn't need to loop through each pair and add them, instead you just need to add the middle pair and multiply that sum by the total number of pairs. This works really well for programming because they aren't looping through each number which in programming would eat through your resources.

You can find the number of pairs by dividing n/2 and it also gives you the middle number then you just add 1 to find its pair.

Let say you are getting the sum of 1-100, by applying Gauss's approach, you'd want 50(101)=5050. 50 is the number of pairs and in the code, it is represented by `n *` and 101 is the addition of the middle pair (50+51) or in the code `(n+1)`, then finally we divide by 2 for the middle number.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function SimpleAdding(num) { 
 
  place = 1;
  i = num;
  do {place = place += i; i--}
  while (i > 1);
  return place; 
         
}
```

You set your placeholder variable equal to one. You also set the number of iterations equal to the input variable.

The do loop then adds your placeholder variable with 'i' and then the loop exits when it is no longer greater than 1, which is correct because you have your placeholder equal to one.

Answer (score 0):

It can be calculated by using the recursion

```
var numberSum = (n, a = n) => n ? numberSum(n = n - 1 , a = a + n) : a
```

Answer (score 0):

I use while loop I think this is more easy

```js
function numberSum(S){
    var a=1;
    var sum=0;
        while(a<=S){
            sum+=a++;
        }
        return(sum);
}
function go(){
    val = document.getElementById("value").value;
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=val+":"+numberSum(val)
}
```

```html
<input id="value">
<input type="Submit" onclick="go();">
<p id="results"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will be helpful in a simple way

```
let n = parseInt(readLine());

let sum = n*(n+1)/2;

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function numSum(n){
    var sum = 0;
      for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        sum += i; 
         }
    console.log(sum)
         }
numSum(15);
```

Comment: u can verify your answer by calling your function.

Comment: Please explain why this solves the OP's problem - code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Based on the code above, print out the sum after the whole iteration and call your function to verify that your code works.

Answer (score -1):

More general answer with recursion.

```
const sumRange = (min, max) => min !== max 
    ? sumRange(min, max - 1) + max 
    : 0
```

While this might not be the most optimal answer for the case of min:0 max:n, it might be the easiest to read and understand.